# Countermeasure to timing attack against SQL SELECT of hash token

Tags: sql, api, hash, timing

We want to create a web API, where users receive hash tokens (196-bit) via email as part of their purchase of our software license and can then use this token to activate their trial software version to the "full" software. The web API is responsible to receive the hash token and confirm or reject the user from upgrading to full.

Leaving out lots of details about this, it seems that receiving a hash token in such a way and then just checking with SQL SELECT if this token is in the database exposes a timing attack. The attacker can attempt to guess individual bytes from the tokens in the database by measuring the response time.

How to guard against this? In general and specifically in Ruby on Rails.

Ideas so far:

- Achieve constant time for the look-ups (how?)
- Add random noise (how much?)
- Split token in key part (32-bit) and remainder. Perform look-up only on key and a secure compare on the rest

Comment: You could obfuscate the query time by adding random waiting before returning the data to the client. This way, the request time wouldn't only depend on the database lookup.

Comment: What would be a suitable amount of time to compensate?

Comment: I guess it has to depend on the average query execution time (but I'm no expert in statistics). If you know the maximum execution time, you could also always maximize the response time with some margin (e.g. always take 10 seconds to respond to such queries). Of course there are still issues with heavy-load situations, but in my opionion, heavier load increases the unpredictability of individal query execution time. In combination with DOS-defense meachanism this makes such attacks unfeasible.

Comment: Adding random timing noise probably doesn't improve security as is laid out [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/can-i-prevent-timing-attacks-with-random-delays).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My working solution using a second indexed token_key field, which is the leading 8 bytes of the token_hash:

```
def valid_token(given_token_hash)

  # don't look for hash, because of SQL timing attacks
  token_key = given_token_hash[0,8]
  token = ActivationToken.find_by_token_key(token_key)

  # Even if not found in database, we should pretend to take some time
  token_hash = token.nil? ? "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000" : token.token_hash

  if (!secure_compare(token_hash, given_token_hash))
    return nil
  end

  return token
end
```

Comment: Theoretically, the hash can collide with another one right? if two tokens have the same 8 first bytes, what should be done then?

Comment: You need to check for collisions when you insert the keys (need to do that anyway).

Comment: I think I misunderstood something, I mean that the tokens are not the same just coincidentally their hashes' first 8 bytes are the same (the rest is not)
Or should I make sure that the 8 first bytes don't collide either?

Comment: To make the proposed solution work the first 8 bytes need to be unique when generating tokens.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that came out when devise removed token_authentication for this reason was to perform the look up based on a public criteria, such as email, and then use a constant time comparison on the hash token found by the query and the one sent in the params. Check the gist on the "safe" version.

https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6#file-2_safe_token_authentication-rb

I believe adding random noise would be futile from a statistical viewpoint, with enough data the randomness should flatten out. Would love love to hear more detail on the internal comparison mechanism of SQL comprisons.

Comment: Thats kind of what I ended up doing: I treat the first 32-bit of the token as public (an integer ID), which will lead to a look-up in the database (timing attacks will work on this). Next secure_compare the remainder.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek do you generate the first 32-bits using an auto incrementing id? If it's random then using the birthday problem you'll have a 50% probability of collision of those first 32 bits at only 77,000 tokens which seems too low

Comment: @danny: I use random, but then check for existing IDs.